# QMessageBox relative centering to the mainwindow

Tags: qt

I have a code, when I click on the push button a message box displays.

**constructor:**

```
window = new QWidget;
button = new QPushButton(window);
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::clickButton);
setCentralWidget(window);
```

**clickButton():**

```
void MainWindow::clickButton() {
    QMessageBox msg;
    msg.exec();
}
```

When I click and run the code, the widget appears in the middle of the screen, and if I click on the push button, the message box also appears in the middle of the screen, this is the way it should be displayed.

When I drag the widget and position it elsewhere, I would like to position it to the center of the widget.

This gives me the center of the widget: `window->mapToGlobal(window->rect().center())`, but the `move` function starting position is in the top left corner, this is my issue, how could I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit a little of your code and your problem was fixed :

To showing message box in the center you just need set window as it's parent

**In mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMessageBox>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

    void  clickButton();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWidget        *window;
    QPushButton    *button;
    QMessageBox    *msg;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**In mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    window = new QWidget;
    button = new QPushButton(window);
    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::clickButton);
    setCentralWidget(window);

    msg = new QMessageBox(window);
   
    //you can comment this line because for show message box in center you just need set window as it's parent
    msg->setGeometry(width() / 2.0, height() / 2.0, msg->width(), msg->height());
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void  MainWindow::clickButton()
{
    msg->exec();
}
```

**Out put :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

By default the QMessageBox will show centered on the parent, and if it has no parent then it will be centered on the screen.

### Solution:

You can set the geometry of the QMessageBox, but for this you must have information about the size, so it must be done after invoking the show method (before that, the size will be equal to the sizeHint, which does not necessarily correspond to the real size).

```cpp
void MainWindow::clickButton() {
    QMessageBox msg;
    msg.show();
    msg.setGeometry(QStyle::alignedRect(
                        Qt::LeftToRight,
                        Qt::AlignCenter,
                        msg.size(),
                        geometry()));
    msg.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the correct solution is to set parent for the dialog box. Firstly, it will center the child message box and secondly it will implement the correct OS-dependent behaviour for modal dialogs. FOr example if you click in area outside the modal dialog, the dialog will flash slightly to notify the user that the dialog is modal.

So instead of this:

```
QMessageBox msg();
```

call this:

```
QMessageBox msg(this);
```

The currently accepted solution which sets manually the center position of the dialog is just dirty hacking. It is not the right solution for dialogs which are child of a parent window, especially modal dialogs. Though you can use it if you want to place a top-level window relative to another window. But not for child dialogs.

PS: Btw. setting the position manually will not work on macOS since there the modal dialogs are usually displayed as "Sheets" which pop up from below the title of the parent window, see https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/sheets/ so if you do want to develop multiplatform software (which is the main usecase for using Qt), just do not set the placement of dialogs manually, use child-parent relationship to your benefit.